# How to avoid business rules in repository?

Tags: domain-driven-design

If there is Employees repository and I have to get Employee that has a greatest salary - where to put filtering that represents business rule for that?
I can get all Employees and filter them out in Domain Model, but that does not seem as efficient as SQL Query in repository. What patterns come into play?

Comment: Why do you feel that your repository is not an appropriate place for business logic/rules?

Comment: @cbojar Rules/Logic for retrieval gets duplicated when switching repositories. But I guess that's evident.. .

Comment: I'm not sure I see where the duplication is. Do you mean you have different versions of your `Employees` repository for each different database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The business logic is not the query that returns the Employee with the greatest salary -- databases are great at that and you should let the database do that for you via the repository. The business logic is what you do after you retrieve the most highly compensated employee.

Comment: If business rule can tell that Employee has to have name and last name, then why it should not specify that Employee with highest salary is one which has salary greater than others when compared? Just because some engine/layer does the job better? What if I switch from database to some other persistence mechanism.. . The "rule" is not encapsulated anywhere. There might only be a method's name in interface that gives a hint - GetEmployeeWithHighestSalary.

Comment: If you switch from database then you have to rewrite your repository. It's still better to filter the employees in the repository than to process them all in the application code.

Comment: @kevin it seems like business rules to me, please don't spoil newbies. The repository is only responsible to fetch and save data period.

Answer (score 1):

Since a salary, its presentation and database computation is quite natural and has no strict domain, I would not call it business logic here. It's just an `ORDER BY` query for the database.

Let me give you another example with business logic:

If you would like to have the most "profitable" employee and there are some domain specific values like "probability of on time completion in projects" and "illness absent factor", and at least the salary, then there might be some weights for calculating the scoring factor which would be business logic.

**Conclusion:**

Keep in mind, that there are frameworks with repositories with no DI, thus just dbal operations are possible. In other words a business logic component should be able to use DI.

In my opinion repositories should be simple and also only depend on the dbal. *Ordering* and simple *where* are okay. *Joining* and computation over different entities is not the job of the repository.

So I would leave the simple queries to a repository which have no business logic and create services for more complex queries, which have business logic.

All in all it's more opinion-based I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to two layers to perform this. One will be the DAO layer and one will be the Service layer. All your business logic have to be defined(or injected from external source) in Service layer. All the methods that you need to retrieve data either from database or some other source should be defined in DAO layer. Service layer will call the DAO layer and apply some rules on top of it and return the result. This will help you complete decoupling of your rules and persistence.

But in your case, executing a direct SQL query with employees having greater salary will have high performance than following Service-DAO pattern.In this case, you can modify your business logic in service layer to pick the appropriate query string in Service layer and pass the query(or where condition of the query) to DAO and get the result.

Comment: Sounds like that I will have multiple representations of the same business rule. Is there some one unit that can accomplish that? For example, I can have query that is used for one mechanism and I can have some sorting loop of all entities for other. Is that related to specification pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Defining what is an Employee (according to your existing storage model) is a Business Rule (it is a definition, so it's a fact).

First article of the Business Rules manifesto (http://www.businessrulesgroup.org/brmanifesto.htm).

Comment: Why should I read that article? You're answer isn't much more than a link.

Comment: Literally and according to the manifesto, your repository may contain Business Rules...

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely OK to implement this low-level in your repository and just proxy it from your service-layer. Something like:

```
// repo contract
public interface IEmployeeRepository {
    public Employee GetHighestPaidEmployee();
}

// service layer contract
public interface IEmployeeService {
    public Employee GetHighestPaidEmployee();
}

// service impl
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService {
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    // constructor here for DI to hook onto

    public Employee GetHighestPaidEmployee() {
        return employeeRepository.GetHighestPaidEmployee();
    }
}
```

Or, if you wanted to be more generic, just implement something like `public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(string sortColumn, SortDirection sortDirection);` on your repository and call it from your service layer using something like `return employeeRepository.GetEmployees("Salary", SortDirection.Descending).FirstOrDefault();`

Excuse my C# leaning, no idea what language you're using. These concepts should translate to other languages, though, I'm just not as familiar with syntax.